# Why is the "add comment" link showing up when I can't actually post a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

I have only 1 reputation, and I see on all questions "add a comment" link.

However when I click it, I get:

> You must have 5 reputation to comment

It means I can't really comment. So why show me the link in such case?

Comment: 1 is less than 5. Just participate and you will get reputation.

Comment: it comes up because you don't have the privilege to [comment everywhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). there are more privileges than that which you will get if you get more rep which you can see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) though do be aware that Beta and Graduated Sites have different rep levels for these

Comment: Not a duplicate, the other one was feature request asking to  add a message when clicking "add comment" without enough reputation, this one here asks the opposite, why this link is showing up.

Answer (score 7):

There is an [old feature request](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61277/make-it-more-obvious-that-commenting-is-only-possible-after-earning-certain-repu/285725#285725) asking to add exactly this behavior, before that there was indeed no link.

As for why it's good to show, it's consistent with other features of Stack Exchange, for example:

- Voting (both upvote and downvote arrows are always visible, even when you can't really vote, with one exception being [historical lock](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for))
- Editing (edit link is always visible, even if you can't edit e.g. pending edit, edit banned etc.)

I see it as a way to tell the user "See what you can do with reputation", so that it gives incentive to gain that reputation.